# PHP:Why printf("%.2f", 0.02) output 0.024?why is not 0.02?

Tags: php, printf

When the code is :

```
<?php printf("%.2f", 0.02);?>
```

> output: 0.02

When the code is :

```
<?php var_dump(printf("%.2f", 0.02));?>
```

> output: 0.02int(4)

When the code is :

```
<?=printf("%.2f", 0.02)?>
```

> output: 0.024

```
<?=var_dump(printf("%.2f", 0.02))?>
```

> output: 0.02int(4)

Why `<?=printf("%.2f", 0.02)?>` isn't outputing `0.02`? Does `<?=printf("%.2f", 0.02)?>` correspond to `<?php var_dump(printf("%.2f", 0.02));?>`?

Comment: What do you mean `0.02int(4)`? Please make it clear the code that reproduces the problem, because AFAIK, PHP doesn't magically spawn a 4

Comment: you might want to put all 4 lines into the one file and separate them with something like a line of `<p>--------------</p>` to show that the 4 isn't coming from some other input

Comment: its hard to understand a while ago, the formatting of the question is all over the place, the OP probably doesn't know how to code format in markdown editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've missed something important here. [From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

> Returns the length of the outputted string.

So, while `printf` outputs to the browser, it returns the **length** of `0.02`, which is 4

Comment: But why <?=printf("%.2f", 0.02)?> output 0.024，<?php printf("%.2f", 0.02);?> output 0.02？

Comment: Because in the first one you are echoing the **return** value of `printf` and in the second you're not